# Host a firebase application with a .com domain

Tags: html, firebase, web, hosting, firebase-hosting

I am new to hosting.

I have a project:
Front end: HTML, CSS, JQuery
Back end: Firebase

And from the website i am saving user data in firebase database. Now i want to host the site as abc.com

So I called goDaddy to know about hosting. They clearly said I can't use a third party database.

Now how can I host the website with .com domain.

P.S: I already know about the firebase hosting and after hosting i got an url like abc.firebaseapp.com and I don't want this I want like abc.com

Comment: Have you tried the office document that I suggest? Let's me know if you still have any issue or ask more specific where you don't understand or get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain
It may take a while to have effect.